# Playframework 2 - Deploying to ec2

Tags: java, git, scala, amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0

I know that i can use the play dist command to upload it to an ec2 instance without any problems but the size is 35mb and I don't want to wait 60min for every tiny change. (I have dsl 1000)

Is it possible to use something like heroku where you just push your changes via git command?

I think that would require a custom AMI with a working play2 installation.

Comment: Do you upload it as a ZIP? (sorry have no experience with ec)

Comment: AWS Beanstalk lets you use git to handle deployments.

Comment: @biesior: I didn't try it yet because the huge filesize scares me. @ Lusitianian: But I am only able to deploy .war files right? That would destroy the purpose of play2.

Comment: Beanstalk only allows war files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use git for deployment, you'll have to install the git server on your EC2 instance.

Then, you'll have to come up with some scripting, by heavily using [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), in particular, the `post-receive` hook on the server side.

Roughly:

1. Execute the `clean`, `compile` and `stage` tasks
2. if everything fines, stop the old play application, and start the new one (in `target/start`)

Comment: you don't need to install git server, you can push to a bare repository via ssh

Comment: Yes, and get it all working with [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) locally first to save yourself some time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dev environment is also on ec2, you are better off creating a new AMI from your dev server reflecting the changes and then deploying that new AMI.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I am able to understand what you are saying because I have very little experience with servers. But can't I just take a ec2 instance, install play2 so that I can use it in the commandline, upload my playfolder (or git) and just do somthing like `play start`?

Comment: @MaikKlein I thought your concern was over trying to deploy code changes to EC2. Once you have a dev/qa/stg environment in ec2 and you want to deploy it to production, all you need to do is create an AMI from the EC2 instance that matches what you want to place into production.  Once the AMI is complete, you just use that AMI to launch new production instances.